# Программа для решения уравнений

Tags: python

```py
import math
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
D=(b**2-4*a*c)
if a==0:
    if b==0:
        print("уравнение не имеет смысла")
    else:
elif b==0
   x1=(math.sqrt(c/a))
   x2=(-math.sqrt(c/a))
   print(x1)
   print(x2)
elif c==0:
    x3=(-b)
    print(x3)
    print(0)
else:
    if D<0:
        print("нет решений")
    elif D==0:
        x4=(-b/(2*a))
        print(x4)
    else:
        x5=(-b+math.sqrt(D))/(2*a)
        x6=(-b-math.sqrt(D))/(2*a)
        print (x5)
        print (x6)
```

после проверки а и b ( после строки else:(того else которое после уравнение не имеет смысла) следующая строка elif подсвечивается ошибкой (expected an indented block) и не дает начать алгоритм. не понимаю как исправить. прога, наверное максимально глупая, но только начинаю
помогите

Comment: Первое `elif b == 0:` <- забыто двоеточие. Второе, непонятно зачем нужен `else:`? После него интерпретатор требует чтобы что-то было, а там ничего нет, вот он и ругается

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо большое, уже сам заметил, что не дописал. да и вообще были косяки и кроме этого, но теперь все хорошо)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а вы не знаете, почему появляется ошибка при вводе дробного числа

Comment: @Максим вы потеряете дробную часть, ибо int(input()) - преобразовывает входящее число к целочисленному типу

Answer (score 1):

У вас с отступами проблемы, после первого `else` ничего не следует, а программа чего-то ждет. Условие `b == 0` у вас стоит 2 раза. Да и в целом, можно решить всё короче и не перебирать столько разных условий, например:

```
import math

print("Введите коэффициенты для квадратного уравнения (ax^2 + bx + c = 0):")
a = float(input("a = "))
b = float(input("b = "))
c = float(input("c = "))

discr = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % discr)

if a == 0 and b == 0:
    print("Уравнение не имеет смысла")
else:
    if discr > 0:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(discr)) / (2 * a)
        print("x1 = %.2f \nx2 = %.2f" % (x1, x2))
    elif discr == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        print("x = %.2f" % x)
    else:
        print("Корней нет")
```